# Ethers: Get transaction hash without sending transaction

Tags: transactions, ethers.js, hash

My transaction fails, so it doesn't give me a hash that I would be able to use to debug it when I call ethers.wallet.sendTransaction(tx). The tx object has 4 fields: from, to, data, value. If I do

```
    const txSigned = await wallet.signTransaction({
      ...tx,
      gasPrice,
      gasLimit: BigNumber.from("2000000"),
    });
    console.log("Tx hash wrong:", ethers.utils.keccak256(txSigned));
```

Then this value that emerges does not in fact match the correct transaction hash. Does anyone know how I can use ethers to get such a transaction hash, to debug the failed transaction? I could manually go to the local chain itself and view the failed tx hash, but that can't be manipulated inside my code itself.

Answer (score 1):

You calculate the hash **correctly** - it is the `keccak256` of a signed transaction. Something wrong is somewhere else.

Try to send that signed tx via [`provider.sendTransaction`](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/provider/#Provider-sendTransaction), as [`signer.sendTransaction`](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/signer/#Signer-sendTransaction) could recalculate gas or smth. else, then the hash will be different.

Or, when manually signing the transaction you miss the `chainId` field and signing via the `Wallet` it adds the `chainId`.

Comment: I think there's a very specific set of fields needed that are signed, and I don't have all of those, and the sign transaction function doesn't give me those

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get transaction hash before the transaction completion. Because to generate transaction hash some fields are required which not available because before transaction completion

Comment: Like what? I don't think this is the case.